# How to retrieve the URL of the current browsed Web page in my application and to add to it some query parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url, hyperlink

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to know how to retrieve the URL of the current browsed Web page in my application and to add to it some query parameter. That is, given a user is browsing the page `http://www.my_application_name.org/articles/2`, I would like to "build" something like `link_to` `http://www.my_application_name.org/articles/2?param1=abc&param2=efg`.

How can / should / could I make that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `url_for` method and pass a ruby hash to add query parameters to current URL. For example,

```
<%= link_to 'Current URL with query params', url_for(param1: 'abc', param2: 'efg') %>
```

That should work.

If you want to get the current URL with `host`, `port` etc., you can use the `request` object to construct one as shown below.

```
<%= "http://#{request.host}:#{request.port.to_s+request.fullpath}" %>
```